# ¿Por qué se me pone el titulo del android:label como titulo de todos mis toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, actionbar

En el manifest tengo como android:label el nombre de mi aplicacion. Este nombre se me pone en todos mis toolbar creados. En el tema quite el actionBar por defecto que te crea. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public class EdicionModulo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar tbEdicionModulo;
    private TextView tvTitleToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edicion_modulo);

        tvTitleToolbar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitleToolbar);
        tbEdicionModulo = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbEdicionModulo);
        setSupportActionBar(tbEdicionModulo);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nModulo = intent.getStringExtra("nombreModulo");
        String estado = intent.getStringExtra("estadoModulo");

        tvTitleToolbar.setText(nModulo);



    }
}
```

En el toolbar me aparece el Texto del android:label del manifest seguido del texto que le pongo a este toolbar. Si le pongo un setTitle(nModulo) me coge solo el texto ahora si del "nModulo" pero el estilo del texto es un poco cutre por lo que quiero hacerlo con un textView para darle la apariencia que le he puesto.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres, quieres poner un titulo a tu toolbar pero lo quieres poner con estilo?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es personalizar el titulo del `Toolbar`, puedes quitar `label` de la `Activiy` que desees del `AndroidManifest` y aplicas las propiedades que necesites en código java/kotlin de la `Activity`.

Comment: Claro, en el manifest en nivel aplication tengo como `android:label` el nombre de mi app, el cual se me pone como titulo de cada `Toolbar` que creo. Lo que quiero es poner como titulo un `TextView`. Lo que pasa es que se me pone el `android:label` del `manifest.xml` junto al `TextView` dentro del `Toolbar`.